# Replace SAS macro loops in R

Tags: r

Say I have the following dataframe and I want to create individual subset dataframes as me1, me2, me3.....

In R I would manually do the following:

```
data1 <- data.frame(a = runif(4),
                    b = runif(4),
                    c = runif(4),
                    d = c("a","a","b","c"))


me1 <- subset(data1,data1$d == "a")
me2 <- subset(data1,data1$d == "b")
me3 <- subset(data1,data1$d == "c")
```

In SAS, I would write a macro loop which is like the following to automatically generate those *meX* datasets:

```
%let vars = a b c;
%do count1= 1 %to 3;
  % let thisVar = %scan(&var.,&count1.);
  data me&count1.;
    set data1;
    where d = "&thisvar";
  run;
%end;
```

Are there similar ways in R to do this?

Thanks!

Regards,
John

Comment: Store the split, but related, data together in a `list` - `dslist <- split(data1,data1$d)` . There is little reason to have `me1`, `me2` etc floating as free datasets in R. Using a list has the advantage of being able to apply a function to all datasets at once, like: `lapply(dslist, function(x) sum(x$a) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `list2env` if individual objects are needed in the global environment.  (I would prefer to place this in a list with `split`). The list elements after the `split` are named as the unique elements of 'd' column that was used for splitting.  Change the names to the preferred one by `setNames` and `paste0` (as there is a pattern for 'me1', 'me2', etc), and use `list2env` so that the individual `me1`, `me2` etc are created

```
list2env(setNames(split(data1, data1$d), 
          paste0('me', 1:3)), envir=.GlobalEnv)

me1
#          a          b         c d
#1 0.1455141 0.02331238 0.5732288 a
#2 0.5377224 0.37848993 0.6632085 a
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks akrun

Answer (score 0):

Probably a silly way to do it, since I'm using lapply and dplyr. Also I'm not naming the items.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data.frame(a = runif(4),
                    b = runif(4),
                    c = runif(4),
                    d = c("a","a","b","c"))

custom.filter <- function(i){
  return(filter(data1,d==i))
}

melist <- lapply(unique(data1$d),custom.filter)
```